# Roslyn scripting engine does not throw runtime exception when used as delegate

Tags: c#, exception, roslyn

I run into troubles using the Roslyn Scripting Engine. I get no exception handling when I run a script within a delegation.

Test that works as expected:

```
string script = @"var a=0; var b=2/a;";
var runner = CSharpScript.Create<object>(script);
var errors = runner.Compile();
Assert.IsTrue(errors.IsEmpty);

try
{
    runner.RunAsync();
    Assert.Fail("Where is the exception");
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    // everything is OK! Error thrown...
}
```

Result: No Assertion. The Exception was thrown.

Here's the text using a delegate object:

Unittest:

```
string script = @"var a=0; var b=2/a;";
var runner = CSharpScript.Create<object>(script);
var errors = runner.Compile();
var delegat = runner.CreateDelegate();
Assert.IsTrue(errors.IsEmpty);

try
{
    delegat();
    Assert.Fail("Where is the exception?");
}
catch (System.DivideByZeroException)
{
    // everything is OK! Error thrown...
}
```

I got the fail message and no exception was thrown.

We cache the delegates to speed up the compilation and during a test we see that runtime exceptions are not thrown. So I wrote the test to reproduce this situation.

I can't find any hint in the docs which describes that there are no exceptions thrown during the invoke.

Can someone give me a pointer or a hint why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. In the first version, you're catching `Exception`, which means that when the `Assert.Fail` is reached and throws `AssertionException`, that exception is then caught and ignored.

   This means that there is no difference between `RunAsync` and delegate here, neither of them throws `DivideByZeroException`.
2. Both `RunAsync` and the `ScriptRunner<T>` delegate *return `Task`*. That means to actually wait for them to complete or to observe any exceptions, you need to use `await`. Once you do that, you will see the `DivideByZeroException` that you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, this explains everything! I didn't realized the delagates async behavior. So I can't use delegates in my situation, cause I don't want to have spawnd threads for very small scripts running as a sort of trigger in our application.

The only solution I see ist to cache the compilation objects and not the delegates. I will to some performance tests to see which solution runs better. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @PeterHeß What makes you think spawning threads is going to be an issue? Especially considering that when the script doesn't use `await`, its execution is not really asynchronous (even if a `Task` is used to communicate its result, which makes `await` necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Main` finishes execution before the scheduler gets a chance to invoke `delegat`. It is a task that will run asynchronously. You can see that when you inspect it in the debugger:

[image]

To force execution inside the scope of the `try...catch`, you can use this:

```
try
{
    delegat().Wait();
}
catch(System.AggregateException ex)
{
    /* the inner exception of ex will be your DivideByZeroException */
}
```

The correct type of exception to expect in this case is the `AggregateException`, [see here why](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx).

A solution with `await` is also possible:

```
await delegat();
```

but this will compile only when the containing method can be marked `async` which is not necessarily what you want (show more of the calling code to clarify).

Comment: The question says the code is from a unit test, so there is no `Main`. And even in that case, just making sure that `Main` doesn't finish too soon e.g. by using `Console.ReadLine()`, wouldn't help.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. See my answer in the post below.